# Why do i get a key error '0' running this code

Tags: python

I get key error 0 when trying to run this code:

```py
# Draw Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(13,10), dpi= 80)
sns.boxplot(x='demand', y='Price', data=df, notch=False)

# Add N Obs inside boxplot (optional)
def add_n_obs(df,group_col,y):
    medians_dict = {grp[0]:grp[1][y].median() for grp in df.groupby(group_col)}
    xticklabels = [x.get_text() for x in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
    n_obs = df.groupby(group_col)[y].size().values
    for (x, xticklabel), n_ob in zip(enumerate(xticklabels), n_obs):
        plt.text(x, medians_dict[xticklabel]*1.01, "#obs : "+str(n_ob), horizontalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':14}, color='white')

add_n_obs(df,group_col='demand',y='Price')    

# Decoration
plt.title('Box Plot', fontsize=22)
plt.ylim(10, 40)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code with the default tips data provided by seaborn:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Draw Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(13,10), dpi= 80)
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=df, notch=False)

# Add N Obs inside boxplot (optional)
def add_n_obs(df,group_col,y):
    medians_dict = {grp[0]:grp[1][y].median() for grp in df.groupby(group_col)}
    xticklabels = [x.get_text() for x in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
    n_obs = df.groupby(group_col)[y].size().values
    for (x, xticklabel), n_ob in zip(enumerate(xticklabels), n_obs):
        plt.text(x, medians_dict[xticklabel]*1.01, "#obs : "+str(n_ob), horizontalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':14}, color='white')

add_n_obs(df,group_col='day',y='total_bill')    

# Decoration
plt.title('Box Plot', fontsize=22)
plt.ylim(10, 40)
plt.show()
```

and it seems to work fine. Are you sure that your dataframe variable df does have the keys 'demand' and 'Price'?

Comment: HI, thank you for the answer, yes i am sure. If i put 'Price' on x and 'demand' on y i get key error "44.0" that is the lowest value of price, 0 is the lowest value of demand. It is like if it returns error on the first value.